# Как работает блокировка ввода в текстовое поле через возврат "break" в обработчике нажатия на кнопки

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Я нашёл эту команду, но я не понимаю как она работает. Если объясните, заранее спасибо

```
txt.bind("<Key>", lambda a: "break")
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас довольно неоднозначный вопрос. В заголовке вы хотите одно, а в содержании другое. Так или иначе я отвечу на оба вопроса. Чтобы в текстовое поле нельзя было вводить символы, вам его нужно просто заблокировать вот этой командой, но только после того, как вы уже вывели сообщение:

```
txt.config(state = DISABLED)
```

А команда:

```
txt.bind("<Key>", lambda a: "break")
```

Превращает ваше текстовое поле в своеобразную кнопку. При нажатии какой - либо клавиши выполняется команда. Вообще, вам лучше прочитать документацию к Tkinter на этом [сайте](http://grep.cs.msu.ru/python3.8_RU/digitology.tech/docs/python_3/library/tkinter.html) здесь вы узнаете много нового о Tkinter.

Comment: effbot?????????

Comment: Да, согласен, но на этом сайте можно просто посмотреть название виджета, его методы и др. Более подробную информацию, конечно же, лучше смотреть на других сайтах.

Comment: Я поменял ссылку, т.к. 1 - сайт был религиозной направленности, 2 - там битый https сертификат

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае вы к события нажатия на любую клавишу привязываете обработчик, который всегда возвращает строку `"break"`, и таким образом запрещает передавать событие другим обработчикам (в том числе стандартному, который вставляет набранный текст в текстовое поле):

> An easier solution is to prevent Tkinter from propagating the event to other handlers; just return the string “break” from your event handler:
>
> ```
> def ignore(event):
>     return "break"
> text.bind("<Return>", ignore)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> text.bind("<Return>", lambda e: "break")
> ```

[Источник](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Более очевидный способ просто блокировать текстовое поле - через свойство `state` либо при создании:

```
txt = Entry(root, state='disabled')
```

Либо уже после создания:

```
txt.config(state='disabled') # или txt['state'] = 'disabled'
```

Вообще, свойство `state` есть не только у текстовых полей, но и у других элементов управления, например у кнопок - у них состояние `'disabled'` блокирует возможность нажатия на кнопку.

См. [The Tkinter Entry Widget](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm), [The Tkinter Text Widget](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

Блокировку события через возврат `"break"` лучше использовать для более сложных случаев. Так можно блокировать событие по какому-то условию, например можно блокировать ввод любых символов кроме цифр:

```
# Возвращать None, если нажата цифра (событие не блокируется), иначе возвращать "break" (событие блокируется)
txt.bind("<Key>", lambda event: None if event.char.isnumeric() else "break")
```